# Doubly Linked list vs Multi-linked list in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

What is the difference between doubly linked list and multi linked list?
It will be better explaining me with the help of a C/C++ program.

Comment: did you write any code for your problem?? My advice try something dont ask for code.

Comment: @  Tomas Lycken:  No.. :-) I am a fresher working in a IT firm. I am now in C project but I am not good in linked lists...

Comment: @someone: I dont have any idea how the nodes are connected in Mutilinked lists, thats why I asked for code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Definition**:

A *multi linked list* is a linked list where each node may contain pointers to more than one nodes of the linked list.

*Doubly linked lists* are a special case of Multi-linked lists. It is special in two ways:

1. Each node has just 2 pointers.
2. The pointers are exact inverses of each other.

**Example**:

*A multi linked list:*

[image]

*A doubly linked list:*

[image]

**Representation**:

*Multi linked list:*

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    vector<struct node *> pointers;
}Node;
```

*Doubly linked list:*

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
}Node;
```

Answer (score 0):

A Doubly linked list is the one in which each node will have 2 pointers, 1 to the node before it and one more pointer to the node after that node.
In a multi linked list there will be several pointers, each pointer ordering the nodes based on some criteria.
The difference is,
In a doubly linked list we can traverse the list in either direction, but it is ordered to form 1 list i.e. `one ordering of nodes`. where as in a multi link list there can be `multiple ordering of nodes`. each pointer may order the list based on different criteria and form a different list when you traverse the list using that pointer.

read [this](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/mlinked-lists.html) to know how multi links are used to get different ordering in a multi link list, based on the pointer used for traversing the list.

Answer (score 0):

Doubly linked lists link the elements in forward, and reverse order.
Multi linked list link the elements in several different ways, which are
not related to each-other.

Answer (score 0):

**Doubly Linked List:** Each node in a doubly linked list holds a link to the previous node(excpet for the first node) and the next node(except for the last node).

```
// Node in a doubly linked list
struct node
{
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int age;
    std::string name;
    struct node *previous;
    struct node *next;
}
```

**Multi Linked List:** The nodes of a multi linked list hold various links organize a collection of elements or maintain multiple order of one set of elements etc.

```
// Node in a matrix
struct node
{
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int age;
    std::string name;
    struct node *next_in_row;
    struct node *next_in_column;
}

// Node for maintaining multiple order of one set of elements
struct node
{
    int id;
    unsigned int age;
    std::string name;
    struct node *next_id_in_order;
    struct node *next_age_in_order;
}
```