# Can multiple linked lists share the same structure?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, macros

I have many structure for different different linked list, all have different data types variables. Like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct scorel {
    int no;
    struct scorel *rp;
};
struct namel{
    char a[10];
    struct scorel *rp;
    struct namel *dp;
};
void main(){
    int i,j,n,m;
    struct namel *temp,*head,*end,**s;
    struct scorel *tmp,*had,*nd;
    clrscr();
    printf("enter no of students");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    end=NULL;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        temp=(struct namel*)malloc(sizeof(struct namel));
        printf("enter name\n");
        scanf("%s",temp->a);
        temp->rp=NULL;
        temp->dp=NULL;
        *(s+i)=temp;
        if(end==NULL){
            end=head=temp;
        }
        else {
            end->dp=temp;
            end=temp;
        }
        printf("enter no of scores");
        scanf("%d",&m);
        nd=NULL;
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            tmp=(struct scorel*)malloc(sizeof(struct scorel));
            printf("enter score\n");
            scanf("%d",&tmp->no);
            tmp->rp=NULL;
            if(nd==NULL){
                nd=had=tmp;
                temp->rp=tmp;
            }
            else {
                nd->rp=tmp;
                nd=tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        temp=*(s+i);
        printf("%s-->",temp->a);
        tmp=temp->rp;
        while(tmp!=NULL){
            printf("%d-->",tmp->no);
            tmp=tmp->rp;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Any **Macro** available for that by which i can use same structure for different different linked list.

I also seen array of linked list,

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head[5];
```

But in this only we can use one type of variable.
I want different different types of variable for every  linked list.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: This is not a C++ question. Please remove the C++ tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your linked lists in 2 ways.

First approach is to add `next` field together with data structure and then you can have this structure accessible on only one list

```
struct myData {
    struct myData* next;
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
}
```

And later, when you add your item to linked list, you simply find last item and you set `last->next = current` and `current->next = NULL;`.

---

Another possibility is to separate structure for your data and for list entry

```
//Linked list structure
struct nodeEntry {
    struct nodeEntry* next;
    void* data;
};

struct myData {
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
};
```

Now, to add your data to the linked list, you would do similar to:

```
nodeEntry* ent = malloc(*ent);
ent->data = pointerToMyData;
ent->next = NULL;

//Now find the last item in linked list and do:
last->next = ent;
```

In second case, each item in linked list has its own `next` object and this allows you to have your single structure of data in multiple linked lists.

This approach is called *multi linked list*

[Doubly Linked list vs Multi-linked list in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808713/doubly-linked-list-vs-multi-linked-list-in-c-c)

Comment: `This approach is called multi linked list` No, it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: It has in fact. Single item can be in multi linked lists.@4386427

Comment: It is not the data that is important. It is the list itself, i.e. what links the nodes together - one pointer or multiple pointes. The link you provided makes that very clear.

Comment: @4386427  with my approach you can use the same data structure for multiple link entries. Of coarse, data entry does not have reference where it is used.

Comment: Yes, a data object can be in multiple lists - true. But that has nothing to do with *multi linked list*.